# Custome Model Browser with checkbox for forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

I wanted to implement custom model browser with checkboxes for forge viewer. Any references for the same.[enter image description here][image: 1]

Comment: Can you be more specific ? What result do you expect ? Have you already tried to do something ? Did you take a look at the [existing samples](https://forge.autodesk.com/code-samples) ?

Comment: Yes I tried implementing it with JStree but it is given us performance issue as we have huge data with us . I'm attaching the expected output in above query. Please check.

Comment: Any idea or update on above query?

Comment: Your problem is more related to performance. There's a lot of subjects about JSTree performance issues with huge data sets. Hard to help you without any information on how you implemented this in your code ...

Answer (score 0):

Check [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/customizing-model-browser-custom-label-behavior-styling-and-data-sources).

```
viewer.modelstructure.tree.delegates[0].getTreeNodeLabel= nodeId => {  
   //your code here, can use NOP_VIEWER.getProperties(nodeid, callback) to get model data ...   
   return yourCustomLabel
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we change styling to use checkbox with each node, using the above code?